# How to send a large input stream to a Spring REST service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Have a Spring Rest application that run inside an embedded Jetty container.
On Client I use RestTemplate(try to).

Use case :

Having an InputStream (I don't have the File), I want to send it to the REST service.

The InputStream can be quite large (no byte[] !).

What I've tried so far :

Added **StandardServletMultipartResolver** to the Dispatcher context;

On servlet registration executed :

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = ...
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("D:/temp");
dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
```

On client :

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        parts.add("attachmentData", new InputStreamResource(data) {
            // hacks ...
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                //avoid null file name
                return "attachment.zip";
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() throws IOException {
                // avoid calling getInputStream() twice
                return -1L;
            }
        }
ResponseEntity<Att> saved = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, parts, Att.class)
```

On server :

```
    @RequestMapping("/attachment")
    public ResponseEntity<Att> saveAttachment(@RequestParam("attachmentData") javax.servlet.http.Part part) {
        try {
            InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
            // consume is
            is.close();
            part.delete();
            return new ResponseEntity<Att>(att, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } 
    }
```

What is happening :
The uploaded InputStream is stored successfully in the configured temp folder (MultiPart1970755229517315824), the **Part part** parameter is correctly Injected in the handler method.

The delete() method does not delete the file (smth still has opened handles on it).

Anyway it looks very ugly.

Is there a smoother solution ?

Comment: `Part#delete()` is supposed to throw an `IOException` if something goes wrong. Does it?

Comment: It calls in turn File#delete() and does not check the return value, failing silently

Answer (score 3):

You want to use HTTP's [Chunked Transfer Coding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1). You can enable that by setting [`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html#setBufferRequestBody-boolean-). See [SPR-7909](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7909).

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use byte[], and write a wrapper around the webservice to actually send the "large string" in chunks. Add a parameter in the webservice which will indicate the "contentID" of the content, so that the other side knows this part belongs to which half-filled "bucket". Another parameter "chunkID" would help in sequencing of the chunks on the other side. Finally, third parameter, "isFinalChunk" would be set if whatever you are sending is the final thing. This is pretty non-fancy functionality achievable in less than 100 lines of code.

The only issue with this is that you end up making "n" calls to the webservice rather than just one call, which would aggregate the connect delays etc. For realtime stuff, some more network QoS is required, but otherwise you should be fine.

I think this is much simpler, and once you have your own class wrapper to do this simple chopping and gluing, it is scalable to a great extent if your server can handle multiple webservice calls.

Comment: It's such a common scenario (I guess), isn't there a recommended approach ... ?

Comment: The uncommonness of the scenario can be from this statement: `The InputStream can be quite large (no byte[] !)` Is it really so large that it wont fit in a byte[] ! If it cant fit, then it really is not a common scenario. Arrays can have really large length btw. Having this said, my knowledge might be short in knowing specific implementations designed for this.

Comment: Well, they can have up to a few gigabytes, so loading it all into memory seems very odd to me

Comment: Hmm. My hands down :)

Comment: Anyways, if it can have upto a few gigabytes, then wouldn't transferring such a large content over the net in one go would result in network problems due to TCP timeouts (transfer time being large due to limited bandwidth)!

Comment: you can increment the timeout of a request as much as you want

Comment: When downloading a file from a server, you just get the outputstrem of the response, write the appropriate headers and just keep writing to it, I thought there smth similar for the vice versa scenario

Comment: 'send the "large string" in chunks.' Hmm… this sounds somehow familiar. Ah, it's [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1).

Comment: Well, except the fact that the "large string" that HTTP 1.1 can accept must be in the RAM completely before making the call. This effectively limits the size of the string to max size of the RAM. Not a couple of tens of GBs.